# Determining vectors array length

Tags: java

```
public class Matrix {
  public static int a = 0;
  public static int b = 0;

  public double myArray[][];

  public Matrix(double a[][]) {
    this.myArray = a;
  }

  public Matrix(int b, Vector... vectors) {

    double myArray[][] = new double[vectors.length][];

    int row = vectors.length;
    Matrix.a = row;
    int column = vectors[0].getYourArray().length;
    Matrix.b = column;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      myArray[i] = new double[row];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        if (b == 0) {
          double[] a = vectors[i].getYourArray();
          myArray[i][j] = a[j];

        } else {
          myArray[j][i] = vectors[i].getYourArray()[j];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public class Vector {

    double yourArray[];

    public double[] getYourArray() {
      return yourArray;
    }

    public void setYourArray(double[] yourArray) {
      this.yourArray = yourArray;
    }

    public Vector(double... yourArray) {
      this.yourArray = yourArray;
    }
  }
}
```

I create 2 vectors array and send them into vector class to make an array which includes these two vectors parameters and then send to matrix class to create matrices with dimension of vector arrays

The problem is that how can i determine the rows and columns of new matrix?

I cannot write a proper code guys please help me

Comment: Get the number of rows (1st dimension) and the maximum number of columns (2nd dimension). There you go.

Answer (score 1):

As you see it in your code:

- 1-th dimension: `vectors.length`
- 2-th dimension: `vectors[0].getYourArray().length`

Normally you also have to ensure, that for all `vectors[0].getYourArray()` the length is the same.